# Как справиться с баном по IP, когда парсер собирает конент?

Tags: curl, php, парсер

Сделал парсер на php соединяюсь с сайтом через curl, куча запросов, сайт который отдает контент естественно себя защищает и банит ИП на время.Пробовал прикрутить список прокси но они тоже по разному некоторые прокси быстро работают некоторые медленно получается картина та же - торомза. Как бы мне не вариант эмулировать пользователя и ждать определенное время между загрузками страниц. Какие есть варианты обхода данной ситуации?

Comment: какой промежуток бана у сайта?

Comment: чем не устроил список проксей и задержкой для каждого? медленные можно выкидывать и на ходу пополнять с какого-нибудь сайта со списком бесплатных проксей. пару тройку быстрых нормальных можно получить.

Comment: в этом случае проще поставить TOR и менять ип для каждого подключения прямо из скрипта. благо это легко делается.  

зыж накручивал один счетчик -- все супер работает, реальный ип не отдается наружу.

Comment: Я понимаю, что такое эмуляция пользователя. В общем штука такая:
есть авито, в нем есть набор объявлений которые меня интересуют, я беру список всех страниц, потом из каждой страницы выбираю все ссылки на детальку, потом проверяю ИД если они у меня есть я их себе не забираю, если нету открываю каждую ссылку и в них получаю фото, детальное описание, цену и телефон который с цифр перевожу в текст. Все очень хорошо получается но если ждать то, полная выгрузка отработает только за 2е суток меня это не устраивает.

Comment: А на мобильной версии та же картина? В любом случае качать меньше, по самым простым прикидкам - раза в 4 :)

Comment: да там еще и задержки на бан меньше и телефоны текстом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Под эмуляцией пользователя понимается не только "ждать определенное время", но еще и запросы сопутствующих ресурсов (картинки, скрипты). Куча запросов это все таки DoS, так что определенного рецепта нет, если конечно сайт не предоставляет API для получения нужных вам данных.

Answer (score 3):

Для начала - посмотреть, есть ли на ресурсах правила для пауков :) В ЖЖ, например, есть, и при их соблюдении никто никого не банит.

Потом, в обязательном порядке работать с If-Modified-Since. Многие сайты корректно отдают Last-Modified и не напрягаются, если отдают 304.

Ну и по возможности всё это проделывать с RSS/Atom, если имеется. И обрабатывать проще, и к их сборщикам отношение, как правило, другое (хотя это, конечно, от задач зависит).

Comment: Замечательные рекомендации но к сожалению ничего подобного мне в данной ситуации не светит.